# Report section style list numbering in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Now I know about the "normal" CSS list styles (roman, latin, etc) and certainly in years past they were somewhat inflexible in not allowing things like:

(a)

or

a)

only

a.

Now I believe that you can get an effect like the above with the :before and :after pseudo-elements.  Is that correct?  And whats the browser compatibility like if you can?

My main question however is that I want to have report style numbering:

1. Introduction
   1.1 Objectives
   1.2 Assumptions
   1.3 Limitations
   1.3.1 ...
2. New Section
   ...

and so on.

Can CSS do this and, if so, whats the browser compatibility like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Generated content, automatic numbering, and lists](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html).

> This example shows a way to number
>   chapters and sections with "Chapter
>   1", "1.1", "1.2", etc.

```
H1:before {
    content: "Chapter " counter(chapter) ". ";
    counter-increment: chapter;  /* Add 1 to chapter */
    counter-reset: section;      /* Set section to 0 */
}
H2:before {
    content: counter(chapter) "." counter(section) " ";
    counter-increment: section;
}
```

Edit: [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) has a better table of css supports on browsers. Almost all browsers, except pre IE8b2 IEs. So yes, totally useless.

Comment: So not IE?  Well thats totally useless then.  Shame.

Comment: why not implement this and have a js fallback for IE6/7 ? Reward the users of advanced web browsers :)

Comment: 4 years later it's totally useful! Although this particular code above doesn't work, check @AmbroseChapel answer at the bottom - according to spec you need to put "chapter" counter-reset in the body to init that var, and "section" reset should be in H1, not H1:before. This way it works like a charm on WebKit for example.

Comment: At least on chrome, it appears that a chapter reset needs to be set on a container of all the H1's. `body { counter-reset: chapter; }`

Answer (score 3):

Here's the W3C specification for CSS2's automatic numbering and incrementing, with an example of 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 type numbering.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#counters

I can't help you with the support question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my complete version of the pure css solution which goes all the way to level h6.
Tested with IE9 and Firefox 28.

```
body {
  counter-reset:level1Header;
}
h1 {
  counter-reset:level2Header;
}
h2 {
  counter-reset:level3Header;
}
h3 {
  counter-reset:level4Header;
}
h4 {
  counter-reset:level5Header;
}
h5 {
  counter-reset:level6Header;
}

h1:before {
  counter-increment:level1Header;
  content:counter(level1Header) ". ";
}

h2:before {
  counter-increment:level2Header;
  content:counter(level1Header) "." counter(level2Header) " ";
}

h3:before {
  counter-increment:level3Header;
  content:counter(level1Header) "." counter(level2Header) "." counter(level3Header) " ";
}

h4:before {
  counter-increment:level4Header;
  content:counter(level1Header) "." counter(level2Header) "." counter(level3Header) "." counter(level4Header) " ";
}

h5:before {
  counter-increment:level5Header;
  content:counter(level1Header) "." counter(level2Header) "." counter(level3Header) "." counter(level4Header) "." counter(level5Header) " ";
}

h6:before {
  counter-increment:level6Header;
  content:counter(level1Header) "." counter(level2Header) "." counter(level3Header) "." counter(level4Header) "." counter(level5Header) "." counter(level6Header) " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple markup example would be:

```
<ol>
    <li>level one</li>
    <ol start="10"> 
        <li>level two</li>
        <li>level two</li>
        <ol start="110">
            <li>level three</li>
        </ol> 
        <li>level two
    </ol> 
    <li>level one</li>
</ol>
```

The result of this is:

```
   1.  level one
        10. level two
        11. level two
             110. level three
        12. level two 
   2. level one
```

Browser support is fairly wide: MSIE6 complies. This is HTML 4.0

Comment: Thats not the numbering I was looking for.  112 isn't the same as 1.1.2.  How would you do 2.11.3.12?  211312?  Doesn't make sense.

Comment: The thing is, since browser support seems to be an issue, CSS is not the answer. Pseudo classes support in MSIE is close to nill.