# Automatic Numbering of Headings H1-H6 using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, automation, html-heading

I read [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535334/html-css-autonumber-headings) posts, but didn't find a solution for IE, so I ask for a jQuery-solution for this problem:

I've some nested hierarchical Headings like this

```
<h1> heading 1</h1> 
<h2> subheading 1</h2>
<h1> heading 2</h1> 
<h2> subheading 1</h2>
<h2> subheading 2</h2>
```

I need some automated headings output like this:

```
1. heading 1
1.2 subheading 1
2. heading 2
2.1. subheading 1
2.2. subheading 2
```

Is there a way how this can be achieved using jQuery or alike, working in IE6+?

Comment: I tend to work on the assumption there should be only **one** `h1` in the page (the page heading), this may, or may not, be of relevance to your structure, though.

Comment: @David: I seem to recall that's what google perfers as well, so that might be relevant :) It would be trivial to adjust the script accordingly.

Comment: @David, that does fit with what I'd heard previously; ...it's weird getting to an age where you've learned stuff and can't remember where it's from... :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

another possibility

```
var indices = [];

function addIndex() {
  // jQuery will give all the HNs in document order
  jQuery('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').each(function(i,e) {
      var hIndex = parseInt(this.nodeName.substring(1)) - 1;

      // just found a levelUp event
      if (indices.length - 1 > hIndex) {
        indices= indices.slice(0, hIndex + 1 );
      }

      // just found a levelDown event
      if (indices[hIndex] == undefined) {
         indices[hIndex] = 0;
      }

      // count + 1 at current level
      indices[hIndex]++;

      // display the full position in the hierarchy
      jQuery(this).prepend(indices.join(".")+" "+this.tagName);

  });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  addIndex();
});
```

Comment: Ah, this is the approach I'm going with as well :) Just a note: if you're having something like `1.2.2.3.1. Very deep header`, it might be immediately followed by `1.3. Subheader`. Deleting the last index is not always enough.

Comment: You are right, i need to fix that. this way it will really look like i cloned you answer ;-). Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me the best result. still tricky when the selector scope is restricted to a special area like ("#content h1,#content h2"), but it works! thanks!

Comment: @honestor, `h1-h7` can be expressed as `:header`, so you could simply do `#content :header`. Another approach would be to pass context to the selector, in which case it'll only search within that scope: `$('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6', $('#content')[0])`. Note that the content parameter should be DOM Node, and *not* a jQuery object. Hence the `[0]`. A simple `document.getElementById('content')` would have done the job as well!

Answer (score 7):

Here's my take on it:

```
var segments = [];

$(':header').each(function() { 

  var level = parseInt(this.nodeName.substring(1), 10);

  if(segments.length == level) {
    // from Hn to another Hn, just increment the last segment
    segments[level-1]++;
  } else if(segments.length > level) {
    // from Hn to Hn-x, slice off the last x segments, and increment the last of the remaining
    segments = segments.slice(0, level);
    segments[level-1]++;
  } else if(segments.length < level) {
    // from Hn to Hn+x, (should always be Hn+1, but I'm doing some error checks anyway)
    // add '1' x times.
    for(var i = 0; i < (level-segments.length); i++) {
      segments.push(1);
    }
  }

  $(this).text(segments.join('.') + '. ' + $(this).text());

});
```

[Working example on all levels, H1 - H6](http://jsbin.com/ahowa3/2)

Comment: thanks for your answer as well, jeromes solution wors a bit better in my environment.

Answer (score 1):

honestor, simply speaking, the problem will be solved once we can get all the `<h2>` tags that follows right after every `<h1>` tag and just before the next `<h1>` tag, right ?

This code has made it and working just fine

```
$("h1").each(function(mainHeadIndex)
 {
     // Numbering the main heads
     $(this).html(mainHeadIndex +1 +'. ' + $(this).html());

     // Find all the h2 tags right under this particular main head
     $(this).nextUntil("h1").filter("h2").each(function(subIndex)
      {
          // calculate the right sub head number
          var newSubIndex = subIndex+1;
          // Numbering the sub heads
          $(this).html(mainHeadIndex +1 +'.'+ newSubIndex +$(this).html());
      });
  })
```

[you can test it on this link](http://jsfiddle.net/QFUnx/17/)

P.S: thanks for you MatejB, I didn't know jsfiddle.com before your post :)

Comment: Thanks David, the code is now updated to  match your scenario.

Comment: another enhancement here is to limit the scope of this code to the 'h1' container to not affect any other **h1**s or **h2**s in the page.

this can be done by starting the script with this line instead of the original one:
by container's tag name: '$('divContainer h1')' 
or by container's ID: '$('#containerID').find('h1')'

Comment: @Mohammed: No worries about the format. The comment markdown is a simplified version of that in the answers. You can click the 'help' link when you're adding a comment, for formatting instructions. Now the code is better in that it doesn't fire on `<p>` tags and similar, but you've reduced your scope to *only* `H1` and `H2`. While those are the only headers in his example, the title says H1-H6. I would expect he wants stuff like *1.1.2.3.1. Very deep subheader*

Comment: @david: exactly, that's what I'm looking for. I like in your approach that it's possible to define the selector, but I still need h3-h6 covered somehow.

Comment: @honestor: hmm, my approach does cover h1-h6...?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
$('h1').each(function(index, element){
    i++;
    $(element).text(i + '. ' + $(element).text());

    j = 1;
    $(element).nextUntil('h1').each(function(subindex, subelement){
        if (!$(this).is('h2')) return; // so subelements other than h2 can be left alone
        j++;
        $(subelement).text(i + '.' + j + '. ' + $(subelement).text());
    });
});
```

[Woking example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MatejB/QFUnx/19/).

Comment: That treats every single element that isn't a `h1` as a subheader. in `<h1>header</h1><h2>subheader</h2><p>paragraph 1</p><p>paragraph 2</p>`, the paragraphs would be prepended with `1.2` and `1.3` respecitvely.

Comment: @honestor I think David Hedlund gave you the best solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wrap H2 subheadings in DIV then use the following code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var result = 0;
    $('h1').each(function(index) {
        $(this).text((index + 1) + '. ' + $(this).text());
        var saveIndexNum = index + 1;
        $(this).next().find('h2').each(function(index) {
            $(this).text(saveIndexNum + '.' +(index + 1) + ' ' + $(this).text());
        });
    });
});
```

## try this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
    var result = 0;
    $('h1').each(function(index) {
        $(this).text((index + 1) + '. ' + $(this).text());
        var saveIndexNum = index + 1;
        $(this).next().find('h2').each(function(index) {
            $(this).text(saveIndexNum + '.' +(index + 1) + ' ' + $(this).text());
        });
    });
});
</script>
<style>
h1
{
     color:red;
}
.subheading h2
{
    color:green;
}
.subheading
{
    background:#e2e2e2;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1> heading 1</h1> 
<div class="subheading">
    <h2> subheading 1.1</h2>
</div>
<h1> heading 2</h1> 
<div class="subheading">
    <h2> subheading 2.1</h2>
    <h2> subheading 2.2</h2>
    <h2> subheading 2.3</h2>
    <h2> subheading 2.4</h2>
    <h2> subheading 2.5</h2>
</div>
<h1> heading 3</h1> 
<div class="subheading">
    <h2> subheading 3.1</h2>
    <h2> subheading 3.2</h2>
</div>
<h1> heading 4</h1> 
<div class="subheading">
    <h2> subheading 4.1</h2>
    <h2> subheading 4.2</h2>
</div>
</body></html>
```