# jQuery automatic heading numbering

Tags: jquery, automation, html-heading, css-counter

I have articles on website with 10-15 H2 tag subtitles. Something likes that.

```
<h1>Name of article</h1>
<h2>Subtitle</h2>
<p>.....</p>
<h2>Subtitle</h2>
<p>.....</p>
<h2>Subtitle</h2>
<p>.....</p>
<h2>Subtitle</h2>
<p>.....</p>
```

So, question is how to give number for each H2 tag (subtitle) automatically by jQuery in descending order?

```
<h1>Name of article</h1>
<h2>15.Subtitle</h2>
<p>.....</p>
<h2>14.Subtitle</h2>
<p>.....</p>
<h2>13.Subtitle</h2>
<p>.....</p>
<h2>12.Subtitle</h2>
<p>.....</p>
```

I know how to do it via CSS counters, but articles can contain different numbers of subtitles. I've checked similar   [Automatic Numbering of Headings H1-H6 using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127017/automatic-numbering-of-headings-h1-h6-using-jquery) topic, but it is not i want exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help

```js
var h2Elements = $('.content').find('h2');
var h2ElemCount = h2Elements.length;
$(h2Elements).each(function(i) {
  $(this).prepend(h2ElemCount - i + '. ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <h1>Name of article</h1>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  <p>.....</p>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  <p>.....</p>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  <p>.....</p>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  <p>.....</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly what I wanted. I've just put article tag instead of .content class.

Comment: One more question: How can I add some CSS class to stylize? I tried to use .addClass('.h2style'); but it doesn't work.

Comment: no need to put '.' (period) inside addClass, you can just do 
.addClass('h2style')

Comment: Maybe, can you help with another problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397234/h2-heading-numbering-doesnt-work-correctly-with-paginated-posts

Answer (score 1):

You can numerate backwards by using the `each` function.

```js
allItems = $("h2").length;
$("h2").each(function (index){
  $(this).prepend(allItems - index + ". ");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Name of article</h1>
<h2>Subtitle</h2>
<p>.....</p>
<h2>Subtitle</h2>
<p>.....</p>
<h2>Subtitle</h2>
<p>.....</p>
<h2>Subtitle</h2>
<p>.....</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var h2Length = $("h2").length;
$("h2").each(function(i,obj) { 
  $(obj).html(h2Length +". "+$(obj).html());
  h2Length--; 
});
```