# H2 heading numbering doesn't work correctly with paginated posts

Tags: jquery, pagination, automation, html-heading

I'm using jQuery script from [jQuery automatic heading numbering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43372393/jquery-automatic-heading-numbering) for H2 subtitle counting. I just updated the script little bit:

```
var h2Elements = $('article').find('h2');            
       var h2ElemCount = h2Elements.length;        
        $(h2Elements).each(function(i) {    
       $(this).prepend(h2ElemCount - i + '. ');    
          });
```

it works perfectly if the article is showed in the single page. When I paginate the post (because there are 10 to 15 subtitles) the counting starts from 1 for each subpage in article. How to keep the heading numbering throw whole article?

Comment: when you use pagination, do you add any querystring to the url (eg: ?page=2)

Comment: No, url finishes like: www.sitename/article name/2. Nothing more.