# Export to Word of Confluence content loses CSS styling

Tags: jquery, html, css, confluence, export-to-word

Hi StackOverflow community,

I am trying to produce a document generator in Confluence 6.10.2 (with JQuery 1.7.2) with a variety of options for the user.

Users can check boxes or radio buttons that will hide/display other pages included via HTML

Once the documents/options are selected, the user can export to Word.

The 1st problem is that the Export To Word option that comes with Confluence exports everything (including the generator and all the sections normally hidden based on the user choices...).

So instead, I create a popup that includes only the user selected elements and then added an "Export To Word" button which uses jquery.wordexport.js as an additional library.

The 2nd problem is that the CSS style is not passed along (still //TODO in that js). As I use CSS counter-reset/counter-increment to have the correct header increments, not having the CSS passed breaks this.

I have tried manually writing the whole jquery.wordexport.js export script into my HTML and hard coding the CSS style, but that does not work either.

```
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Export-Html-To-Word-Document-With-Images-Using-jQuery-Word-Export-Plugin/FileSaver.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Export-Html-To-Word-Document-With-Images-Using-jQuery-Word-Export-Plugin/jquery.wordexport.js"></script>

...
    // Open popup
    $("button#submit").click(function(){
        var htmlContent = $( "#schedMaster" ).html();
        $( "#schedulesDiv" ).html(htmlContent);
        $( "#schedulesDiv" ).find(".noprint").remove();
        //$( "#schedulesDiv table, #schedulesDiv td" ).css("border", "1px solid black");
        $( "#schedulePopup" ).show();
    });

    $("button#exportWord").click(function(event){
        $("#schedulesDiv").wordExport();
    });

});
</script>

<div id="schedulesOverlay" style="display: none;" tabindex="0" class="aui-blanket"></div>
<div style="margin-top: -265px; margin-left: -433px; width: 1065px; height: 530px; z-index: 3004; display: none;" id="schedulePopup" class="aui-popup aui-dialog">
    <h2 class="dialog-title">Schedules</h2>
    <div class="dialog-page-body">
        <div style="height: 413px; padding: 20px;" class="dialog-panel-body">
            <div id="schedulesDiv">...</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dialog-button-panel">
            <button id="exportWord">Export to Word</button> <button id="close">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

NOTE: if I remove FileSaver.js and jquery.wordexport.js, the Export to Word button still produces a file... No idea why but wonder if the Atlassian JQuery implementation does not include similar function?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out pseudo element such as ::before cannot be passed along when exporting to Word.

So instead, I am re-writting the headings with alpha/numerical values using the function in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5127570/11760815, before exporting to Word.