# How to add section numbers (1.2, 3.4.1) automatically using CSS?

Tags: html, css, formatting

How to add section numbers (1.2, 3.4.1) automatically using CSS?

I currently have

```
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
h1 { font-size: 140%; }
h2 { font-size: 120%; color:#049;}
h3 { font-size: 110%; color:#06C;}
h4 { font-size: 105%; color:#09C;}
```

How to modify them so section numbers such as 1.3, 2.4.5 are automatically constructed depending on the nesting level and order of appearance of the section headers?

```
...

<h2>heading21</h2>
...

<h3>heading31</h3>
...

<h2>heading22</h2>
```

should show

1. heading21

   1.1 heading31
2. heading22

or something along those lines.

Comment: You mean, adding section numbers to the headings provided in your markup? Or supplying the heading automatically based on nesting level?

Comment: This may or may not depend on your markup, i.e. whether you use `h1` for the top level sections, `h2` for the second level, etc. For more complex nesting scenarios this may get unwieldy.

Comment: Anyway, check out [automatic numbering and CSS counters](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counters), with excellent browser support (IE8+ and almost all versions of all other browsers).

Comment: Your `...` sections aren't very informative. Are we to assume that your heading tags are all siblings and there's no nesting of divs or sections whatsoever?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML / CSS autonumber headings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535334/html-css-autonumber-headings)

Answer (score 24):

Hey now you can used **CSS counter-increment Property**

As like this 
**Css**

```
   body {counter-reset:section;}
    h1 {counter-reset:subsection;}
    h1:before
    {
    counter-increment:section;
    content:"Section " counter(section) ". ";
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    h2:before
    {
    counter-increment:subsection;
    content:counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
    }
```

**HTML**
**

```
<p><b>Note:</b> IE8 supports these properties only if a !DOCTYPE is specified.</p>
<h1>HTML tutorials</h1>
<h2>HTML Tutorial</h2>
<h2>XHTML Tutorial</h2>
<h2>CSS Tutorial</h2>
<h1>Scripting tutorials</h1>
<h2>JavaScript</h2>
<h2>VBScript</h2>
<h1>Heading </h1>
<h2>One </h2>
<h2>Two</h2>
```

**

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/PfcX2/1/

More info click here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-increment

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "IE8 supports these properties only if a !DOCTYPE is specified."?  What exactly do I need to do to make this work for IE8?

Comment: This works but it creates a `1` in the HTML even there is only one `<h2></h2>` tag.  Is it possible to avoid that?  I.e. number it only if there are more than one of the same-level headings.

Comment: @Robhit Azad, so if there are only one instance of `<h2></h2>`, is it possible to suppress its index number automatically? I.e the numbering is only necessary/useful where there are multiple heads at the same level.

Comment: When there is only ONE `<h1>`, how to avoid numbering it -- i.e. only display top-level numbering if there are multiple top-level sections?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question "If I only have an `h2`, how do I suppress the leading `1`?": alter the `h2::before` style selector so the `h2` must follow the `h1`:

```css
h1::before ~ h2::before {
  // your h2 attributes go here
}
```