# Automatic referencing with javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to write some some javascript code that will place a label in part of a document that can be referenced at another point of the same document.

I am trying to do in javascript what is commonly done in LaTeX with the \label and \ref commands for the theorem environment.
I have searched the web extensively, and also posted a question on Stack Overflow over a year ago, but got no answer. I then posted a question on the LaTeX StackExchange site but was told that this is a question for StackOverflow.

In LaTeX, one would write

```
\begin{theorem}
\label{Th}
If $a$ and $b$ are numbers, then $a+b=b+a$
\end{theorem}
```

The program would assign an automatic label, like Theorem 3, depending on how many other theorems are present before that one. The label is automatically adjusted by the program if another theorem is inserted before that one. Then one can reference the theorem at a different point of the document with \ref{Th}, for example:

```
According to Theorem \ref{Th}, $3+2=2+3$.
```

Comment: Isn't it (= ability to put hyperlinks) the responsibility of HTML? How do you see the workflow, and how's JS involved?

Comment: It may be the responsibility of HTML.  I do not know enough HTML and know very little javascript. But I was told on the LaTeX forum that what I try to do should be done in javascript.  I am not sure about workflow either, but I see the program as assigning a label such as \label{Th} to a section of the document. The label is converted to a number displayed on the web page (as in "Theorem 3"). Then if at a different point of document I write Theorem \ref{Th} the web page will show "Theorem 3". The key part is that the displayed number is automatically updated to "Theorem 4" if needed.

Comment: The numbering can be done with CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535334/html-css-autonumber-headings/535390#535390

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an anchor tag with the hyperlink reference attribute set to the id of whatever you want it to link to.

As an example, my answer has an id of `57526684`, so putting `#57526684` at the end of the url will automatically scroll the page to my answer.

Somewhere on your page:

```
<h1 id=header1>Header 1</h1>
```

Somewhere else on your page:

```
<a href='#header1'>Click to go to header 1</a>
```

Clicking on the link will scroll the page to the header that it's linked to.

---

After seeing your comment, perhaps this is what you're looking for.

Give your theorem headers a data-label attribute which must be unique. You can display a count if you which by using a span tag with a `theorem-count` class.

If you want to refer to a specific theorem by number later on you can use an anchor tag with a `data-referto` attribute containing the unique name of the theorem you want to refer to. You can display it's number inside that anchor tag the same way as with the header. Clicking the refer link will navigate to the matching theorem.

```js
var labels = {};

document.querySelectorAll('[data-label]').forEach((ele, cnt)=>{
  ele.querySelector('.theorem-count').innerHTML = cnt+1;
  ele.setAttribute('id', `theorem-${cnt}`);
  labels[ele.getAttribute('data-label')] = cnt;
});

document.querySelectorAll('[data-referto]').forEach((ele, cnt)=>{
  var label = ele.getAttribute('data-referto');
  ele.setAttribute('href', `#theorem-${labels[label]}`);
  ele.querySelector('.theorem-count').innerHTML = labels[label]+1;
});
```

```html
<h1 data-label='fancy-theorem'>This is thereom <span class='theorem-count'></span></h1>

<h1 data-label='less-fancy-theorem'>This is thereom <span class='theorem-count'></span></h1>

<h1 data-label='super-fancy-theorem'>This is thereom <span class='theorem-count'></span></h1>

<a data-referto='less-fancy-theorem'>Go to theorem <span class='theorem-count'></span></a>
```

Comment: well, this would be how such a program would work. i don't speak latex so all his examples look like latin to me.

Comment: I understand that this will allow to navigate to that point on the page, but I just need to be able to display on the web page "Theorem 3", where the "3" is automatically generated by the code. It should become "4" if I insert another theorem before it.

Comment: @Valerio - see my edit. is that what you're looking for?

Comment: This is some of it, about half. The other half is that there should be a label defined exclusively for Theorem 2, say \label{MyTh} that I can use to reference Theorem 2 at some other point of the document. So if 500 lines later I say "As we discussed in Theorem \ref{MyTh} ..." the output will be "As we discussed in Theorem 2..." A key part is that the numbering should be adjusted automatically, so that if I insert another Theorem before the current Theorem 2, then Theorem 2 becomes Theorem 3, so that when I type \ref{MyTh} the display will be Theorem 3

Comment: @Valerio - that sounds like the first part of my answer.

Comment: @I wrestled a bear once. - I had by mistake submitted my comment before I had finished writing it.

Comment: @Valerio - ok. i gave it one more shot. hope that helps.

Comment: @I wrestled a bear once - It looks like this  is just what I need, but unfortunately I seem unable to replicate it. My experience with javascript is well approximated by zero. Is it right that the code must between the tags <script> and </script> and put inside <head> </head>?

Comment: @Valerio - it should be in a script tag which should be just above the closing body tag (`</body>`) - in other words, it should be the last thing inside the body tag. if you put it in the head then more code is required to ensure the page has loaded first.

Comment: Yes, it works fine now and it's exactly what I was looking for, thank you...I made one small modification that seems to work without side effects: if I do not want the referenced theorem to be a hyperlink, as in "According to theorem 2...",  I replace the <a></a> tag with <p></p>.

Comment: @Valerio - glad that worked for you. a `<p>` is block level, it will work if that's what you want, but if you're referring to a theorem mid-sentence for example, a `<span></span>` would be a better choice, and it's ok to have a span inside another span.